# How to generate seperate plots without using filter and facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to plot individual plot, but not using `facet_wrap` due to my huge number of variables (the plot looks very clustering). I use `filter` to isolate each variable to create a new df, then plot with this df. It works but very inefficiently. I am wondering if there is a better way to do it. Below is my example code

```
df<-data.frame("condition" =c("A","B","B","A","A","B"), 
"day"      = c("D1","D1","D2","D2","D1","D4","D3","D3","D2","D4","D3","D1") ,
"pressure" = c(3,4,5,3,2,9,2,3,5,6,7,8) )

df_D1 <-df %>% filter(day=="D1") #loop through D1-D4 

ggplot(df_D1, aes(condition, pressure))+  # change df manually
    geom_boxplot()
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: you could try using the `facet_wrap_paginate` from the `ggforce` package to split your facets over multiple pages. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggforce/vignettes/Visual_Guide.html#pagination

Comment: There are several SO posts where people split a large data frame into a list of smaller ones, then use `apply`/`purrr::map` functions to create plots of each

Comment: @GordonShumway this function looks pretty nice, thanks! although set `page` to 4 according to this example code, I still can't get individual 4 plots as I wish.